Flux pinning upon a ultracold vapor of neutral atoms
Suppose I have a mixture of two different atoms A and B, both with an even but different number of electrons which fully fill both of their outermost shells. The two are different elements.
Now, suppose I turned both into an ultracold vapor. Atom A had a strong magnetic dipole, while atom B has a negligible one.
In this situation, could a superconductor and flux pinning be used to separate atom A and B at scale during their ultracold atomic vapor state?

Can you clarify the question a bit? Are we assuming that we can bring a superconducting material near the atomic cloud? Can the geometry of the trap be whatever we want it to be, or are geometric details part of the question?

This sounds like both a hard experiment and a hard question. Unless the forces due to the superconductor are too weak, is which case there might be an easy 'no' answer.

@user34722 Yes, I am considering bringing a stream of atoms near the superconductor. However, the crux is if flux pinning effects are possible, so I don't care about geometry.

@user34722 Even if such forces are weak, they may result in seperation if done repeatedly similiar to ion exchange methods.

@user34722 Hello, would you like more specifics to this problem?
